# How to set the X range in Androidplot?

Tags: android, androidplot

I'm passing Androidplot a series with x-values ranging from 0 to 100, but I only want to display the range from 90 to 100. How can I accomplish this?

The graph is redrawn with new data every second. My plan is to call some command before `redraw()` that sets the x-axis range as I want it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setDomainBoundaries`:

```
setDomainBoundaries(90, 100, BoundaryMode.FIXED );
```